# JS Prototype for PhoneGap?

Tags: javascript, cordova, prototype

I'm trying to write an app in PhoneGap with JS. I just started and the first thing I need to do is make a wrapper class for my maps to handle some additional functionality. I'm familiar with js prototype and have gotten used to using it for everything. It doesn't seem that PhoneGap accepts it. Can I used js prototype in PhoneGap and if not how do I handle inheritance?

```
    function Map(){}
    Map.prototype.DOM = null;
    Map.prototype.GMap = null;
    Map.prototype.initOptions = null;

    Map.prototype.init = function()
    {
        alert();
        this.initOptions = { 
            zoom: 1,
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };  

        this.GMap = new google.maps.Map(this.getDOM(), this.initOptions);
    }

    // Modifiers

    Map.prototype.setDOM = function(DOM)
    {
        this.DOM = DOM;
    }

    // Accessors

    Map.prototype.getDOM = function(){return this.DOM;}
    Map.prototype.getGMap = function(){return this.GMap;}
```

Comment: Why would you edit my code to your preferences. I prefer the opening blocks to be on a new line.

Comment: I can understand changing js to JavaScript but the code format is mostly opinion. Some people prefer the starting block on the same line as the method call, if statement, or loop but I prefer it on the line beneath it. I find it quicker to interpret control structures that way at a glance.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question the answer is yes- you can. It works right out of the box.

I had a syntax error and though it wasn't working because of prototype.